# What is a term for the elements of a balance sheet?

Tags: terminology, balance-sheet, assets, liabilities

What is a term for the elements of a balance sheet? Specifically I need a term that includes assets, liabilities, and owners equity. This term (t) needs to be one where I can say x "is a" t where x varies over the terms assets, liabilities, and owners equity.

Comment: Haven't really come across any unified term for the above perhaps you could consider 'Net Worth Measures' ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would refer to that most simply as "position". Its not perfect but I think it fits your use above.

> The balance sheet is also known as the **statement of financial position** and it reflects the accounting equation. The balance sheet reports a company's assets, liabilities, and owner's (or stockholders') equity at a specific point in time.

http://www.accountingcoach.com/accounting-equation/explanation